# Token authentification with DRF not active

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I'm a beginner with DRF (Django Rest Framework).
I'm trying to use an authentification with a Token in my api calls.

I've done this :

1- When creating new user :

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.conf import settings

# This code is triggered whenever a new user has been created and saved to the database
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

2- Create :

```
./manage.py createsuperuser --email f.user@blahblah.com --username fabrice
```

The 2 tables (**authtoken_token** and **auth_user**) are ok.

But when I call the API, if a **don't add the token**, the api's is working :( :

```
$ http -a fabrice:azerty12 http://127.0.0.1:8000/firerisk/highway/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 179
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 12:49:10 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Vary: Accept
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "XXX"
    },
    {
    ...
    ...
```

But, **only this call must working**, no ?? :

```
http -a fabrice:azerty12 http://127.0.0.1:8000/firerisk/highway/ 'Authorization: Token a840a16a3cd43e346f7a3e1442fce0acdf51d609'
```

And, if I don't use the authentification, it's **fail**, and **it's ok** :

```
$ http http://127.0.0.1:8000/firerisk/highway/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 12:25:44 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Vary: Accept, Cookie
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="api"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "detail": "Informations d'authentification non fournies."
}
```

## Update :

my settings.py :

```
    # the REST Framework
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_extensions',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

and a ViewSet (ModelViewSet) :

```
class HighwayViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows highway to be viewed
    """
    serializer_class = HighwaySerializer
    # Authentification !
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Highway.objects.all().order_by('name')
    # Only 'get' method
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

I'm wrong ?

Thanks for help.

F.

Comment: It's seems that, if I call the api like this, it's working  (not mentioning the username/password) : http  http://127.0.0.1:8000/firerisk/highway/ 'Authorization: Token a840a16a3cd43e346f7a3e1442fce0acdf51d609'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the basics first. What is HTTP, what is HTTP headers, what is Django session (it's not an HTTP header and contents of the session doesn't affect the headers), read Django REST Framework documentation on token authentication.

If you want to test your views in browsers, then explicitly allow Django Session authentication in the DRF DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES configuration variable. It can coexist with token authentication.

You can't make plain web browser append token to the HTTP request unless you're using some plugin like RESTClient, or DHC or REST Easy.

You're adding token to the Django session but you have disabled session authentication in DRF and even if you'd enable it, DRF doesn't read token from Django session because API client has no way to add Token to the Django session. Even if DRF would read Token from Django sessions it would be totally pointless as the client has no control over contents of th

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I know all of this :). But not, the entire DRF concepts. I've didn't mention the settings.py. I've adding all the right code in INSTALLED_APPS and REST_FRAMEWORK variables. My comment above is working.